# CSS/JS not loading

Tags: magento2, javascript, css, magento2.4.2

I am using Magento 2.4.2, I've moved from a VPS to dedicated, on the VPS everything was working , but after moving css/js are not loading, already corrected permissions and regenerated static files, do you have any hints on solving this please.

.htaccess exists in home, pub, and var

Already tried

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                      
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                      
find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;             
find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 777 ./app/etc
chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml
```

and

```
rm -rf var/*
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf pub/static/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by CSS/JS not loading?  404 on storefront for the assets?  The html source isn't including these assets?  They're not on disk? etc. etc. etc.  Also what's your PHP version?

Comment: this is how the website is loaded 
https://snipboard.io/qSpj20.jpg

Comment: and this is the console errors 
https://snipboard.io/qjItfc.jpg
https://snipboard.io/u7YXEW.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Check your domain and the static content URL in `store > configuration`. If the domain is mapped on the `pub` directory then the static URL should not include the `pub` directory and if it is mapped on root then the static URL should include the `pub` directory.

e.g
with pub
https://www.example.com/pub/static/version123456789/*/*

without pub
https://www.example.com/static/version123456789/*/*

Also, check ownership of the static directory. e.g www-data:www-data

I hope you'd find this answer useful

Comment: Thanks for the help, the domain isn't pointing to pub directory,
static directory is owned by the cPanel user

Answer (score 0):

Open your `core_config_data` table in phpMyAdmin.

Changing `web/secure/use_in_frontend` **1** to **0**

Run the all Magento Commands.

**Note:** Before changing the value, It's advisable to take db backup.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't solve the issue